# Storing timestamp as Timestamp object in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Feels weird to ask a question that's been asked and answered before, but I did search before posting.

So I want to store a timestamp in Firestore but its either being stored as String or Map, but not as the Timestamp object.

- `new Date()` is stored as a String
- `Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())` or simply `Timestamp.now()` is stored as a Map (seconds and nanoseconds)

I'm importing the method like so:
`const { Timestamp } = require("firebase/firestore");`

Probably worth mention, this is a cloud function that I'm testing locally via `node filename.js`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the Timestamp object from the same SDK as the one performing the upload? (i.e. `import { Timestamp, getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore"` or `import { Timestamp, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"`)

Comment: It looks like the native timestamp is a POSIX/Unix timestamp, not a JavaScript Date() object. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

Comment: @samthecodingman Ok, I tried using both from `firebase-admin/firestore` but still stores as a Map

Comment: @RonnieRoyston The serializer is meant to be [automatically converting](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/789d9eb7f54b5329b17ef759f29252d17da47e26/dev/src/serializer.ts#L139-L157) `Date` objects (even Moment.JS dates) to Timestamps automatically.

Comment: @eozzy Can you provide a screenshot of what you are seeing in the database? Maybe it's just a cosmetic change to the console introduced when they started showing `__name__` fields.

Comment: @samthecodingman No, so if I click on it the popup that opens shows 'string' in the 'type' dropdown.

Comment: Can you show the client side code you use to store `new Date()`? In my app, I store dates in Firestore and they are converted to Timestamp server side

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation on the [Timestamp class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp), a Timestamp stores the date in a second or nanosecond format. Just like you noted, this is why you are not seeing a true Date object stored in the firebase.

In my general experience, I usually use dates stored as string or timestamp representations in a database. The service getting those date values must convert the fetched data into a data type the service can use. Below are a couple of examples for fetching and storing date data:

```js
// To store a timestamp using the Timestamp class:
const date = new Date();
const timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(date); // 1676660310262
// store timestamp in database as Timestamp (results in Map)

// Once timestamp is extracted:
const fetchedTimestamp = 1676660310262
const fetchedDate = new Date(timestamp) // 'Fri, 17 Feb 2023 18:58:30 GMT'
```

```js
// To store a string date, use a UTC string to maintain timezone:
const date = new Date(); // Fri Feb 17 2023 11:58:30 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
const utcDate = date.toUTCString(); // 'Fri, 17 Feb 2023 18:58:30 GMT'
// store utcDate as a string

// Once date is extracted:
const fetchedUTCString = 'Fri, 17 Feb 2023 18:58:30 GMT';
const fetchedDate = new Date(fetchedUTCString) // Fri Feb 17 2023 11:58:30 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```

My recommendation would be to store dates in a Timestamp or string representation. Then in the service reading/writing that data, you should parse the data into a `Date` object on read and from a `Date` object to the string/timestamp on a write.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried using `new Date()` a few seconds before writing this post. It seems to work. I am using the *Modular Firebase SDK for JS* v10.x.x

I did an experiment writing this first (since `serverTimestamp` is Firestore's own implementation of Timestamp):

```js
 function onAddPostButtonClick() {
        setDoc(doc(db, 'posts', uuidv4()), {
            url: uploadedFileURL,
            tags: selectedTags.map(tag => tag.id),
            createdAt: serverTimestamp()
        })
    }
```

Then this:

```js
function onAddPostButtonClick() {
        setDoc(doc(db, 'posts', uuidv4()), {
            url: uploadedFileURL,
            tags: selectedTags.map(tag => tag.id),
            createdAt: new Date(),
        })
 }
```

In the Firestore DB Console, both are resulting in this:

[image: Firestore DB Console]

Hovering over it, we can see, this is the `timestamp` data type

[image]

My *guess* is that like others have pointed out, Firestore uses a hogher resolution format that the native JS `Date()` but the SDK probably pads some zeroes to make it less accurate and more compatible. Again, you may want to verify this if you need ms / ns level accuracy.

For all those asking why can't we just save it as a string, this is because any order by timestamp in Firestore Queries won't work. They'll start ordering by Text instead of Date. So 21-Aug-2018 > 18-Aug-2024.

Answer (score -1):

Firestore does not store [JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects. See [Supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). It appears they store in sub-millisecond resolution [high resolution time](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/) like `window.performance.now()`. You should be able to pass a JavaScript `Date` object as a value though with `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());`

> Date and time:    Chronological:  When stored in Cloud Firestore, precise
> only to microseconds; any additional precision is rounded down.

Comment: Pretty sure `new Date()` stored a timestamp before. I've used in one of my previous apps.